# Can't close Kendo UI Window from AngularJS Controller?

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope

In my controller I'm using this to open my Kendo UI Core window:

```
$scope.winQuestion.setOptions($scope.DlgOptions);
$scope.winQuestion.open();
```

This is the code in my html:

```
div kendo-window="winQuestion" k-title="'Question 1'" k-position="{ top: 60, left: 100 }"
     k-width="730" k-height="300" k-visible="false"
     k-content="{ url: 'questions.html' }"
     k-on-open="winQuestion = true" k-on-close="winQuestion = false" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></div>
```

Now inside that questions.html I have a button that I try to trigger this in the same controller thats inside of another function where I process a cancel click:

```
  $scope.winQuestion.close();
```

This call which in my search for answers on StackOverflow is supposed to work just returns:

TypeError: $scope.winQuestion.close is not a function

I suspect that its a scope issue but not sure why because I get into the

```
   $scope.closeWindow = function(){
      $scope.winQuestion.close();
    };
```

Sorry I don't have a plunker for this but couldn't get kendo core ui to work there, only locally.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but from what it looks like you are overriding the variable of the window, with `true/false` in the `k-on-open` and `k-on-close` events.

When you open the window with `$scope.winQuestion.open();` the `on-open` event will set `$scope.winQuestion = true;`.
So all subsequent method calls on `$scope.winQuestion` are no longer made on the reference of that window, but instead on a boolean value (which does not implement an `open()` function)

Comment: So then all I would need to do is set the value to false? I actually ditched using Kendo UI window because I'm also using Angular Material drop downs which for some odd reason render behind the window no matter what you do with the z-index. I ended using Material window and its awesome! Thanks for your input.

Comment: The simplest way to make it work, would be to remove the `k-on-open` and `k-on-close` attributes.
Or you could use a different variable in there, if you want to control the visibility of a different button for example.